# Toggle the cinema mode on Youtube with Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to enable the cinema mode on Youtube using the [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). I can do things such as playing the video and changing the volume:

```
myPlayer = document.getElementById('movie_player')
myPlayer.playVideo()
myPlayer.setVolume(80)
```

(I typed these lines in the [Firefox console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console))

But I can't find a function to enable the **Cinema mode**:
[image: Cinema mode]

Does anybody have an idea?

**EDIT:**

I also looked at the **Local Storage** and **Session Storage** with the [Firefox Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) but I didn't see any change when I toggled the **Cinema mode**.

**EDIT 2:**

I found the code that corresponds to the button in the Inspector:

[image: Cinema mode in the Inspector]

Is there a way to trigger the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to click the button programmatically:

```
>> collection = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-size-button')
>> button = collection.item(0)
>> button.click()
```

I didn't find a way to get the current state (enabled/disabled).

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [Jcc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584026/toggle-the-cinema-mode-on-youtube-with-javascript/53584337?noredirect=1#comments-link-53584337), I managed to get the current state:

```
>> collection = document.getElementsByTagName('ytd-watch-flexy')
>> ytd_watch_flexy = collection.item(0)
>> ytd_watch_flexy.theater
"false"
```

However, `ytd_watch_flexy.theater = true` makes the video player totally black. So it can't be used to switch on the theater mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
const theaterButton = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-size-button')?.[0];
// The click below forces #player-container-inner 
// to indicate if theater is activated.
// If there is children on player-container, 
// it indicates that theater mode is active.
theaterButton?.click?.();

const isDefaultView
    = document.getElementById('player-container-inner')?.children?.length === 0;

if (isDefaultView) {
    // Clicking the default view button, will switch the view to theater.
    // We cannot call the click directly; 
    // otherwise, the browser will consolidate the two click events,
    // and will not perform the second click
    setTimeout(() => theaterButton?.click?.(), 1);
}
```

Comment: Seems like the youtube site has changed. Here's a way to check the isDefaultView that works with the current page. 

`document.getElementById("masthead")?.getAttribute("theater")?.length >= 0` 

You can test by dropping into the debugger on a youtube video page and pasting the js into the console, then toggling theater mode.

It does NOT require first clicking on the theaterButton, so the solution can remove the `setTimeout()` w/ the second click event?

Comment: Thanks @TrophyGeek, that's an improvement, it's less hackish. I'll try that on next release of my [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-words-separator-c/gacfacdpfimbkgcnlegknnmcccjgcbnp). FWIW, the old approach is still working. The second click is for toggling the view to theater mode. Hmm.. on your new approach, that's just for reading the theater mode status; but how to toggle the view to theater mode?

Comment: My [Open source chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-maximizer/cdnlfphfngnfhjcnoikfhaomaaflaiie) now detects and toggles theater mode using the check provided.

Answer (score 0):

The "cinema mode" is a specific option and isn't provide with the api.

It is logic because the display is relative to each project and isn't possible to wide it everywhere.

Comment: So is there another way to enable it? I had a look at the local storage but I didn't see anything (cf. my edit).

Comment: The way to enable it and the associated style is relied on the "theater" property on the "ytd-watch-flexy" component.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with the accepted solution. Alternatively, you can target the video container HTML element with `let video = document.querySelector('.html5-video-container')`, and compare its width with the window's width `video.offsetWidth == window.innerWidth` to determine if theater mode is active.